# Memory Management with NSDecimalNumber: How to avoid memory problems in tight loops?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uikit

I have a tight loop that iterates about 500 times. In every iteration, it will create a few NSDecimalNumber objects to do some arithmetics.

Example - this code snippet is in the for loop. the -decimalNumberByAdding: method creates a new NSDecimalNumber instance and autoreleases it.

```
resultDecimalNumber = [resultDecimalNumber decimalNumberByAdding:anotherDecimalNumber];
```

So let me get that right: If the loop is huge, I collect thousands of NSDecimalNumber objects which wait for the whole loop to finish and the method to return, in order to get autoreleased after long time waiting.

How could I prevent a memory overflow? I've always tried to use non-autoreleased objects, but in this case it seems I have to live with them.

Imagine this was my loop:

```
for(i=0, i<500, i++) {
    resultDecimalNumber = [resultDecimalNumber decimalNumberByAdding:anotherDecimalNumber];
}
```

What would I have to add there? Must I create a autorelease pool inside the loop and drain it? Would that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should create your own autorelease pool inside the loop. This is exactly the situation that nested autorelease pools are for.

Comment: Although Brad Larson provided a better solution for the problem itself, Rob Napier's answer was correct for the question itself, so I decided to check this one. To all: See Brad's post for a better solution regarding the usage of NSDecimalNumber.

Answer (score 3):

Use the C struct NSDecimal.  From Apple's ["Number and Value Programming Topics for Cocoa"](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI):

> You might consider the C interface if
>   you don’t need to treat decimal
>   numbers as objects—that is, if you
>   don’t need to store them in an
>   object-oriented collection like an
>   instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.
>   You might also consider the C
>   interface if you need maximum
>   efficiency. The C interface is faster
>   and uses less memory than the
>   NSDecimalNumber class.
>
> If you need mutability, you can
>   combine the two interfaces. Use
>   functions from the C interface and
>   convert their results to instances of
>   NSDecimalNumber.

I use NSDecimal, rather than NSDecimalNumber, on the iPhone for this very reason.  You get all the precision of NSDecimalNumber, with a lot less overhead.

Benchmarking the two on my Mac (MacBook Air, 2nd gen), gives these results:

```
NSDecimal
Additions per second: 3355476.75
Subtractions per second: 3866671.27
Multiplications per second: 3458770.51
Divisions per second: 276242.32

NSDecimalNumber
Additions per second: 676901.32
Subtractions per second: 671474.6
Multiplications per second: 720310.63
Divisions per second: 190249.33
```

Even ignoring the memory usage, you get a near fivefold speedup in every operation but division if you use NSDecimal and the C APIs.

Comment: Thanks mate. Gonna take a look on that.

Comment: +1 Very nice benchmarks. I knew about the C interface but didn't know what kind of speed you'd see with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the builtin floating-point equivalents for the `NSDecimalNumber`s you are using, then cast the result back into an `NSDecimalNumber` at the end of the loop:

```
double total(0);

for (i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
{
    total += [anotherDecimalNumber doubleValue];
}

resultDecimalNumber = // turn total back into an NSDecimalNumber
```

This technique will not only save you heaps of memory allocations inside the loop, but will also be significantly faster because you'll be using on-chip math operations instead of firing off functions.

Comment: This isn't desirable if you want to maintain precision and avoid floating point errors.  You might as well not use NSDecimalNumber to begin with, and instead rely on a double value, if this is the approach you're going to take.

Comment: Agreed. The only reason to break out NSDecimals in the first place is because double math isn't appropriate for your problem. If anything, one might go the other way in a few cases (do high-precision math with NSDecimals and return a double at the end), but I can't imagine using the above approach.